# Converting POJO to SOLR query

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Is there any way to convert the POJO to SOLR query.

```
class Sample{
@Field("id")
String id;
@Field("name")
String name;
.
.
.
}
```

Is there any way to convert the above pojo to SOLR query

Example : `id:"123" AND name:"qwerty"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to [query by example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example)? In that case your sample is not quite right.

Comment: Need to parse the Java - POJO to Solr query. Is there any API to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data With Solr Maybe??
You may find these of some help:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/
- http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/

Answer (score 0):

There is none: you will need to write your own, taking care of escaping etc.